# Exponentialish matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

"Explain why $e^{A(t+T)}=e^{At}e^{AT}$ using the formula $e^{At}=Se^{\Lambda t}S^{-1}$."

I really don't know where to start with this. For clarity $\Lambda$ is the diagonal eigenvalue matrix. $S$ is the eigenvector matrix. I can't tell from the context if $T$ is a matrix or means transpose.

Comment: If you can't tell what $T$ is from the context, how do you expect anyone else to?

Comment: @Aweygan hoping someone will recognize from experience what this is asking.

Comment: well, t and T are scalars.

Comment: From the context, it seems that $t$ is probably a scalar.  Since $T$ is being added to $t$, it seems to me that $T$ should also be a scalar.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what $t + T$ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $t$ and $T$ are scalars and that, since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, the matrix $e^{\Lambda t}$ denotes the diagonal matrix whose entries are obtained by replacing the diagonal entry $\Lambda_{ii}$ with $e^{\Lambda_{ii} t}$. Then

$$
e^{At}=Se^{\Lambda t}S^{-1},\qquad e^{AT}=Se^{\Lambda T}S^{-1},\qquad e^{A(t+T)}=Se^{\Lambda (t+T)}S^{-1}.
$$

Now since $e^{\Lambda (t+T)}=e^{\Lambda t}e^{\Lambda T}$ (since this holds for scalar exponentials and therefore for diagonal matrices), it follows that
$$
e^{\Lambda(t+T)}=Se^{\Lambda (t+T)}S^{-1}=Se^{\Lambda t}S^{-1}Se^{\Lambda T}S^{-1}=e^{\Lambda t}e^{\Lambda T}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We are given that

$$e^{At}=Se^{\Lambda t}S^{-1}$$

Then, using $I=S^{-1}S$, we have

$$\begin{align}
e^{A(t+T)}&=Se^{\Lambda (t+T)}S^{-1}\\\\
&=Se^{\Lambda t}e^{\Lambda T}S^{-1}\\\\
&=Se^{\Lambda t}(S^{-1}S)e^{\Lambda T}S^{-1}\\\\
&=e^{\Lambda t}e^{\Lambda T}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve this answer too. As always, I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful, I am happy to delete it. -Mark